# Want to overlay a density plot with a grid of graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a GraphicsGrid object:

```
mycircle = 
  GraphicsGroup[
    {Circle[], Arrowheads[.2], Arrow[{{0, 1}, {0.1, 1}}], 
     White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2]}];

circles = 
  GraphicsGrid @ 
    Table[Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[
        mycircle, 
        ShearingTransform[RandomReal[-1, 1][[1]], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]], 
      {10}, {10}]
```

That produces the grid

[image]

I need to put it on top the DencityPlot:

```
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Using `Show` doesn't work.

Comment: The coordinates of `circles` are nowhere near the coordinate range of your `DensityPlot`, which is why `Show` seems to fail.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with `GraphicsGrid` and `Overlay`, but you get visual centering of the distorted circles rather than precise centering at specific lattice points.

```
mycircle = 
  GraphicsGroup[
    {Circle[], Arrowheads[.2], Arrow[{{0, 1}, {0.1, 1}}], 
     White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2]}];

SeedRandom[42];
circles = 
  GraphicsGrid[
    Table[
      Graphics[
        GeometricTransformation[
          mycircle, 
          ShearingTransform[RandomReal[-1, 1][[1]], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]], {10}, {10}],
        PlotRangePadding ->
          {{Scaled[.12], Scaled[.07]}, {Scaled[.11], Scaled[.07]}},
        ImageSize -> {400, 400}];

plot = DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}];

Overlay[{plot, circles}]
```

[image: overlay]

Answer (score 4):

```
mycircle = GraphicsGroup[{Circle[], Arrowheads[.03], Arrow[{{0, 1}, {0.1, 1}}],
   White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2]}];

circles2 = Graphics[Table[GeometricTransformation[mycircle, 
   Composition[AffineTransform[{{{1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}}, {i, j}}], 
    ShearingTransform[RandomReal[-1, 1][[1]], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]], 
  {i, -9, 9, 2}, {j, -9, 9, 2}]];

Show[DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], circles2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `Inset` and specify the position of the circles by hand:

```
mycircle = 
  GraphicsGroup[{Circle[], Arrowheads[.2], Arrow[{{0, 1}, {0.1, 1}}], 
    White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2]}];
circles0 = 
  Table[Graphics[
    GeometricTransformation[mycircle, 
     ShearingTransform[
      RandomReal[-1, 1][[1]], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]], {10}, {10}];
background = DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
Show[{
  background,
  Graphics[
   MapIndexed[
    {g, idx} \[Function] Inset[g, 2 idx - 11, {0, 0}, {1, 1}],
    circles0,
    {2}
    ]
   ]
  }]
```

[image]